Docker install on mounted volume in NTFS
I am running windows 11, I've downloaded docker for windows, and ran the installer.
when trying to run the docker command which works for my college I get this error.

Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/Projects/path-to-project': mkdir /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/Projects: file exists

C:/Projects folder is not a normal NTFS folder on my machine. It's actually a separate hard drive which is a Mounted Volume at C:/Projects
I've tried mounting this C:/Projects drive in WSL by following these instructions: Mount a Linux disk in WSL 2
This works if I do the commands as follows:
  mkdir /mnt/test
  mount -t drvfs C:/Projects /mnt/test

Then I can list files in this drive within WSL, but the path is wrong, so Docker still fails to run the way it does on my collogues machine.
If I try this
  mount -t drvfs C:/Projects /mnt/host/c/Projects

I get this:

mount: /mnt/host/c/Projects: bad option; for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount. helper program.
dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
<3>WSL (10235) ERROR: UtilCreateProcessAndWait:687: /bin/mount failed with status 0x2000

The problem seems to be that this path '/mnt/host/c/Projects' already exists since it is the NTFS "mount" point, but WSL is not able to understand it at all. for instance:
  ls -al /mnt/host/c/
  ...
  ls: /mnt/host/c/Projects: cannot read link: I/O error
  ...

So this path doesn't even have traditional metadata that ls can read.
Is there any way to get WSL to mount this drive at this location simultaneous to Windows being able to have the drive mounted there?
For now I can move the files I have to a folder in my C drive, but I would like to be able to run docker in this mounted drive as well.
